# I need to upgrade a version of @babel/core inside of react-scripts, how can i do that?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-core

I would like to update the version of the @babel/core lib inside of the package.json of the react-scripts (it was installed @5.0.1), can i achieve that through npm run eject ? Or it needs to be done in another way?
Thank you in advance :)

I wanted to upgrade a version of @babel/core on a create-react-app project.

Comment: The way i solved this was migrating the app from create react app to vite. Followed this example from Robin Wieruch - https://www.robinwieruch.de/vite-create-react-app/